# Cronjob to delete specific files by extension after x mins

Tags: cron, cpanel

Ok so I need to make a cronjob that will delete all the .exe files from a specific directory in my cpanel account.
my home folder is "/home/Name"
the folder that contains the .exe files located at "/home/Name/public_html/Folder"
I'd like to set it to delete all the .exe files there every x min, say 5 mins.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Enter to the `cpanel` and go to `Home » Server Configuration » Configure cPanel Cron Jobs`

Enter the following values:

- Minute: `*/5`
- Hour: `*`
- Day: `*`
- Month: `*`
- Weekday: `*`

In the `Command` text box enter: `rm -rf /home/Name/public_html/Folder/*.exe`

The following steps are equivalent to crontab field:

```
*/5 * * * * rm -rf /home/Name/public_html/Folder/*.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Linux terminal type:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and following the instructions in the file that gets opened.

Comment: Ask them to send you the SSH username and password.